# MVC 4 and Twitter Bootstrap. Website links don't work on some mobile devices

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Using MVC 4 and twitter bootstrap, I have created a website that works fine all desktop units.  But for some reason, many of the links don't work on my phone (Galaxy s3) or my wife's tablet ( Nexus 7 ).  It's really weird because some of the menu system works and some of it does not. Also some links on pictures don't work and some do. I am so confused, I have no idea where to start looking.  How can I get my website to be more stable on all devices?  Any help is appreciated.

Example of dropdown menu links:

```
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/carpet-cleaning" title="">Carpet Cleaning</a></li>
                <li><a href="/upholstery-cleaning" title="">Upholstery Cleaning</a></li>
                <li><a href="/house-cleaning" title="">House Cleaning</a></li>
                <li><a href="/tile-and-grout-cleaning" title="">Tile & Grout Cleaning</a></li>
                <li><a href="/air-duct-cleaning" title="">Air Duct Cleaning</a></li>
                <li><a href="/dog-cat-urine-cleaning" title="">Pet Spots & Odor Removal</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Example of picture links that won't work:

```
<div class="row col-xs-12" style="display:table">
   <div class="center col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <br /><br />
        <img src="../../Images/VideoPlaceholder.png" class="img-responsive" style= "width:100%" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="row col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 service-tiles">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
            <a href="/carpet-cleaning" title="" onmouseover="this.title=''">
                <div class="sq_titles">Carpet Cleaning</div>
                <img src="../../Images/ServiceTiles/tile_carpet_cleaning.jpg" class="img-responsive services-tiles" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="/upholstery-cleaning" title="" onmouseover="this.title=''">
                <div class="sq_titles">Upholstery Cleaning</div>
                <img src="../../Images/ServiceTiles/tile_upholstery3.jpg" class="img-responsive services-tiles" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="/house-cleaning" title="" onmouseover="this.title=''">
                <div class="sq_titles">House Cleaning</div>
                <img src="../../Images/ServiceTiles/Maid.jpg" class="img-responsive services-tiles" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="/tile-and-grout-cleaning" title="" onmouseover="this.title=''">
                <div class="sq_titles">Tile/Grout Cleaning</div>
                <img src="../../Images/ServiceTiles/tile_tile-cleaning2.jpg" class="img-responsive services-tiles" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="/dog-cat-urine-cleaning" title="" onmouseover="this.title=''">
                <div class="sq_titles">Pet Spots <br />& Odors</div>
                <img src="../../Images/ServiceTiles/tile_puppy.jpg" class="img-responsive services-tiles" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="/air-duct-cleaning" title="" onmouseover="this.title=''">
                <div class="sq_titles">Air Duct<br />Cleaning</div>
                <img src="../../Images/ServiceTiles/tile_duct.jpg" class="img-responsive services-tiles" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You generally shouldn't put `row` and `col-*` classes on the same element. Put them on separate `<div>`s and nest the `<div>`s instead.

Comment: `style="display:table"` WTF?

Comment: Also, you have a bunch of redundancy in your classes. `col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6` is the same as simply `col-sm-4 col-xs-6`.

Comment: Didn't know that.  I will implement those suggestions. style="display:table" was something I was trying. But, it did not work, it a remnant and will be deleted.  Thank you for the comments.